# meaning of independent samples

Tags: independence, definition, pseudorepliction

I am getting confused about the concept of independent samples, which is related to the concept of pseudoreplications. This question is related to [this topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26237/dependent-vs-independent-samples). But reading it does not make it clear for me.

Suppose we are interested in the population of Germans (of a specific age, to be more specific). The response variable is height. We have obtained truly random samples from the population. However, within the samples, there is certainly some correlation structure (e.g., sex). But is it okay to treat all samples as independent of each other? We want to perform a one-sample t-test. We are not interested in a difference due to sex.

I am not asking how to account for such nuisance factors (e.g., sex) in statistical models. I want to know whether the samples in the example are considered independent. Whether they are independent or not, I want to understand the intuitive meaning of 'independent'.

The answer from the previous post says that they are independent because a person’s height has no bearing on another person’s height. But by using the same logic, I feel that two plants in the same agricultural plot can also be considered independent [if the two plants have no interactions at all] even in the presence of plot effects, which are usually considered non-idependent in a study with multiple plots.

The ability to recognize correlation structure in data depends on our knowledge (and thus subjective). If we do not know the concept of sex, we cannot recognize potential differences between sexes. Likewise, there are many different levels of correlation structure based on other attributes of samples in most sample populations.

Answer (score 0):

A sample is called independent, if the chance of item $A$, say, being selected for the sample is not influenced by other items in the sample. For simplicity, consider a finite population containing among others items $A$ and $B$, and let $S$ denote an independent sample, then it must hold that $P(A\in S \wedge B\in S)=P(A\in S)P(B\in S)$.

If you have some extra information about the items, such as sex in your example with the Germans, or the plot your plants grew in, then you will indeed see correlation between the elements in your sample when you take that information into account. This is due to the correlation that already is present in the whole population, and it does not invalidate independence.

If you however use that information to generate your sample, then independence is lost. In the agricultural example, one often samples the same number of plants in each of the plots, deliberately bringing structure into the sample. This *stratified sampling* is done because the plot itself can have a considerable influence on the outcome, say height of a plant. Within each plot, the items are sampled independently. If the total sample has size equal to the number of plots, then only one plant from each plot can be in the sample, therefore, for two items $A, B$ from the *same plot*, $P(A\in S \wedge B\in S)=0\neq P(A\in S)P(B\in S)$. If “plot” influences the outcome, then stratified sampling yields more precise estimates than simple independent sampling.

The issue of *pseudoreplications* arises in the example of sampling from plots, if you restrict sampling to a random subset of plots, or if you sample preferentially from some of the plots. This *cluster sampling* results in less precise results; e.g. estimation variance will be higher than under independent sampling. Again, we can make up an extreme example: a sampling scheme that first selects one of the plots, and then samples independently within the plot. Then you would get that $P(A\in S \wedge B\in S)=0\neq P(A\in S)P(B\in S)$ for $A$ and $B$ from *different* plots.
If such samples are analysed with methods that assume independent samples, the predicted spread is biased towards small values. You would get error bars and confidence intervals that look nicely short, but are deceiptive.

Even when plants from different plots or Germans from the population have been sampled independently, one often finds the statement (in text books or in the literature) that the observed values are “not independent”. This may really sound confusing, but could be understood as dependence between the variable of interest and the additional variables. This dependence motivates the use of this extra information when analysing the data, which can yield more precise results or more powerful tests. As long as the analysis ignores the extra information, the data should be considered independent.

Answer (score 0):

*Greetings!*

*This is my first ever answer. I'm not an expert at this presumably, still I'd like to give a shot.*

Before we dive into ' What does it mean for two samples to be Independent ', let's see what Independence means in different contexts:

**➢ Independent Processes & Events:**

Let's say we are tossing a coin for 4 times one after the other.  Say, Event1 = getting head in first toss and, Event2 = getting head in second toss. Then we say that probability of occurrence of Event2 is not influenced by the occurrence of Event1 if the underlying random process is independent.

That is P(Event2|Event1) = P(Event2), And this would mean Event2 is independent of Event1. This can be alternatively stated as P(E1,E2) = P(E1)*P(E2). We can extend this to continuous distributions as well. (f(X|Y) = f(X)). In our context (The German population example), we could define events such as P(height<160cm), P(height<175cm) and these would be dependent events as per the probabilistic definition and a bit of common sense.

**➢ Independent Features:**

If we take Height and Sex as two features in the German population example, then we are basically asking the same question of is P(height|sex) = P(height).  To make it clearer, it's like asking what's the probability that my height lies in a certain range given that I'm a Male. If this wasn't any different than when I hadn't told that I was a Male, then the height and sex of the population are said to be independent features.

To be more specific, the height of person is independent of his/her sex in this case and providing the sex doesn't provide any additional information. We can in-fact use this idea to exploit the dependency between features and make predictions. This is a well-known use case of Bayes Theorem.

**➢ Independent Samples? :**

When we are talking about samples, we generally talk in terms of linear independence and a term called correlation becomes more relevant here. The correlation between the samples is said to be 0 if they are linearly independent, and non-zero if they are linearly dependent. Linear independence here means that any sample cannot be written as a non-trivial linear combination of the others. This is useful in compression & eliminating redundancy, getting an idea about our dataset, etc.

If we still persist on thinking in terms of 'Independence' as being able to derive one sample from the other, I feel that any number of samples can never be 'Independent'. I feel that we can come up with an nth order polynomial or at least some function, that exactly fits all these points, and that way relates them with one another.

**So, I think it all boils down to how we define our problem statement and what our motive is.**

*This is just my perspective and intuition on things. Some of the above stated things could be wrong and it's entirely possible that I'm completely mistaken.*

*I may have been assertive at some places but that's more like a way I'm accustomed to and doesn't relate to my confidence on the correctness of the statements. I'd like to use this line as a substitute for adding 'afaik','iirc' after every line.*

*Thank you.*